# Sql server query with CTE containing CLR returns empty string after joining to more than 5 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Kind of a weird one.
I have a CTE, it selects 3 columns.  and id, then two varchar fields.  The varchar fields use a CLR function to concatenate names with a '/' dividing them.

I run this query on 5 environments and on 4 of them it returns the names with the '/'.
On the other environment, it's empty string (all enviros/servers have same copy of db).

Running the CTE body returns data fine on all environments.

In commenting out sections of the sql, data is returned fine until I join to more than 5 tables (even if the table has nothing to do with the query).  Just seems that no matter what table I join to, after 5 joins my varchar data becomes empty string.  If I filter out for a specific id, data is returned fine.

Im guessing there's some sort of environment config that's different on the one environment compared to the others.  Anyone have any idea?

```
with my_cte as
(
    select  my_id,
            dbo.List(names1, '/') names1,
            dbo.List(names2, '/') names2
    from table
        where blah= blah
)

select  A.some_field,
        OU.names1,
        OU.names2
    from myTable A
        inner join my_cte OU on (OU.this_id = A.this_id)
        inner join table3
        inner join table4
        inner join table5
        inner join table6 --once i get here, no matter what table6 is, the names1, names2 become empty string
    where A.blah = xxxx;
```

Comment: Where are your `ON` clauses? The addition of a `JOIN` isn't going to affect the data returned from a different object (though as it's an `INNER JOIN` it will affect the number of rows, both positively and negatively).

Comment: Use `left join` to keep rows even when there is no match.

Comment: The ON clauses just grab data from other tables and are all fine.

Comment: No need for LEFT join.  Im not missing any rows.  My CTE varchars just change from string values to empty string

Comment: is dbo.List() a custom aggregate? could you check whether the execution on the "other" server uses parallelism?

Comment: *" My CTE varchars just change from string values to empty string"* Adding a `JOIN` to `table6` won't make that happen. If it does, you need to show us a replication, as we can't run what is above (because we don't have the object, nor is it valid T-SQL). We really need a [mre] here.

Comment: dbo.List() is a custom aggregate, parallelism is the same on the servers

Comment: Larnu - I cant give you an example you can run because you wont have the CLR.

Adding another join does cause me an issue, only on this one box.  This code has existed for a few years and runs fine on 4 of 5 servers so im assuming there's a setting somewhere screwing this one up.

Comment: check if the execution is in parallel. For testing, execute the problematic code with OPTION(MAXDOP 1) and see if it makes any diff. Did you use the sample, custom aggregate code from BOL (that code would not concatenate when parallelism was triggered (it would miss (a) delimiter)..?

Comment: OPTION(MAXDOP 1) seems to help my stripped down version of the sql.  i'll try with the full sql

Comment: Ok, seems OPTION(MAXDOP 1) will stop the varchars from becoming empty string, however, each server has the same setting for max degrees of parallelism as 0, so it can use all cpus avail

and again, the query works on the other boxes that have the same max degrees.  weird weird

Comment: Things to check: whether the CLR code has potential threading bugs that might cause it to fail if run in parallel, if the servers have different versions (might be a solved bug in the engine) and whether the DB compat levels are the same across servers (recent versions of SQL Server introduced changes in how functions are evaluated and inlined; this should have no effect on CLR functions, but you never know). Also, trace flag 8649 can be used to force parallel execution and manifest the bug if the non-repro is because the other servers decide on a sequential plan (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix was to rewrite the CTE into a temp table until dba's check the config diffs between the boxes.  Thanks for the comments.